# How to troubleshoot subdomain issue on Aegir

Tags: aegir

I set up Aegir on a rackspace server. Everything works correctly. I then create a new site and set the url to testname.mydomain.com. After Aegir is don provisioning the site I go to the front page at testname.mydomain.com and see my new site. The front page works fine, but every other page, gets a page not found error, so when I attempt to login I'm unable. How do I go about troubleshooting this issue.

So it turns out this is somehow related to platform, I added another platform based on makefile (for open atrium) and it seems to work correctly, I'm not really sure why this would happen, but I figured I would update incase anyone else is having the seam issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your platform is most likely missing the .htaccess file in its top-level directory, or (less likely, or else the Aegir interface itself would likely show the same problem) mod_rewrite is not enabled on your site.

See if you can get to http://testname.mydomain.com/?q=user

If that works, but http://testname.mydomain.com/user doesn't, then your .htaccess file is missing or being ignored by Apache.

Comment: The first works but the second does not, I get a 404 error. It seams that the hostmaster folder does have a .htaccess in it but the individual sites do not. I'm not sure how this is intended to be set up in Aegir, and idea what modifications I can make to get this to work?

Comment: It is not hostmaster platform you should look inside, but the platform that you are using to provision your new website. If you are using hostmaster profile for your new websites it means that you are doing it wrong.